# Fixing damaged partition map. Couldn’t modify partition map. (-69874)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, big-sur

I am trying to fix my external hard disk but when I use first aid from disk utility, it throws an error:

[image]

My Mac was able to read this hard disk till yesterday before I tried to force mount it using terminal. Now it just throws an error:

[image]

Please someone help me read this HDD, I need to recover my data.

Comment: The hard drive could be failing. Or there's just a problem with the partition map that macOS can't fix. In either case, if you really value the data and don't have a backup of it, I'd recommend you stop messing with it and send it into a data recovery place. In the future, backup you data!

Comment: I tried to recover the data using this software (https://recoverit.wondershare.net/buy/recoverit-data-recovery.html?) and it recovered all my files which I deleted like 1 year ago almost 800GB's. But it did not recover anything that was in the drive at this point of time. What do I do? :( @At0mic